# jScrollPane & jQuery 1.6 compatibility

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I was wondering if anyone knew the best version of jScrollPane to use with the newest version of jQuery.

I am using jQuery 1.6.4

I have tried jScrollpane 1.x, 2.0beta10, and HEAD from github, none of them seem to work, or even behave in quite the same way. I am of the opinion that this is likely a version compatibility issue because what I am doing doesn't seem that exotic.

I am using a div with:

```
.scroll-pane {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%
}
```

and calling jScrollpane as follows:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('.scroll-pane').each(function() {
    var api, jsp_resize_timeout;
    $(this).jScrollPane();
    api = $(this).data('jsp');
    jsp_resize_timeout = void 0;
    return $(window).bind('resize', function() {
      if ($.browser.msie && !jsp_resize_timeout) {
        return jsp_resize_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          return api.reinitialise();
        }, 50);
      } else {
        return api.reinitialise();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The scrollbar doesn't even appear until I resize the window. I am guessing that the API is for some reason not being initialized. Once I resize, i get scrollbars but scrolling doesn't work. The div just flickers. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to add the link. You may download it from here : http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

If you get the files off the jScrollPane git hub account, including mousewheel, it all works with jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score -1):

Try Jquery version 1.4.2. The latest version of Jscrollpane is not compatible with jquery 1.6.4.

You may download ( or simply include) this version from [here].

Thanks!

Comment: Link? Where did you find this info?

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
I faced a similar problem and found everywhere they are using the version 1.4, so I used that and worked fine for me.